# Restore database which have blank record in between the data from .dat(backup) file in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, database, restore

I have database backup in .dat file format. It contains 1 table having around 100 000 records. 
As I successfully restored the database I got 93 000 records. 
there is 1 blank record in the table, all the records above that blank record are restored (93 000 records) and records below that are missing.(7 000 records). 
I tried to restore it with below queries.

```
    RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK='D:\BackupFile.dat'

    RESTORE DATABASE MyDatabase FROM DISK='D:\BackupFile.dat'
    WITH
    MOVE 'BackupFile_DATA' TO 'D:\MyDatabase.MDF',
    MOVE 'BackupFile_LOG' TO 'D:\MyDatabase.LDF'
```

the .dat file contains the database backup which was made on MS SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Is this mysql or sql server? The syntax looks like sql server. I have read this question over and over and I just can't make heads or tails of what you are saying.

Comment: this is sql server 2005. i have edited the question description, kindly read this again.

Comment: What is a blank record? As posted your question just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the format, but in case it's plain text (like T-SQL or CSV), open it with a text editor and remove the 'blank' record before restoring.

Comment: PS- Blank records refers o an entirely empty row. 
Actually, I and my colleague got the task to restore the database from the .dat file into SQL server 2005, when he performed the task he got 109000 rows in which one row is totally blank. I restored the database using the above-mentioned query. it successfully executed but the total records in my restored database were 93000. when I check with his DB, the first 93000 records before the blank were exactly same whereas the rest of the records after that blank were missing in my DB.